# Justify Chinese characters with PDFKit

Tags: python, html, pdf

When I use PDFKit, a Python library to generate a PDF file based on local HTML, everything is okay except that Chinese characters do not justify in the PDF file.

I have set `text-align: justify; text-justify:inter-ideograph` attributes for HTML body. The HTML rendering is okay for the contents.

How can I solve this problem?